# Case insensitive HasSuffix in Go

Tags: go, case-sensitive

I am looking for specific file types from a directory listing and use HasSuffix to do the comparision looking for a few specific file types. I would like to make this comparison case insensitive.

Is there a way to add EqualFold or another case insensitive comparison to the HasSuffix function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just use

```
if strings.HasSuffix(strings.ToLower(s), "suffix") {
    // do something 
}
```

You can also write your own wrapper function:

```
func hasSuffix(s, suffix string, caseSensitive bool) bool {
    if caseSensitive {
        return strings.HasSuffix(s, suffix)
    }
    return strings.HasSuffix(strings.ToLower(s), suffix)
}
```

For file names or paths you can use (see answer of PeterSO):

```
if strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(s)) == ".fileending" {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I can't be sure of the "suffix" case so I will ToLower that as well, that seems to make the most sense. 
if strings.HasSuffix(strings.ToLower(s), strings.ToLower(extension)) {
    // do something 
}

Comment: `HasSuffix()` is better than `filepath.Ext()` even for filenames when you know the extension(s) you are interested in. Some filenames have more than one extension, e.g. `tar.gz`. `HasSuffix()` can be called in exactly the same way to handle both the single-extension and multi-extension cases.

Answer (score 3):

> "I am looking for specific file types from a directory listing. I would like to make this comparison case insensitive."

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func hasExts(path string, exts []string) bool {
    pathExt := strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(path))
    for _, ext := range exts {
        if pathExt == strings.ToLower(ext) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    dir := `./`
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    sourceExts := []string{".go", ".Py", ".c", ".cpp"}
    for _, fi := range files {
        if hasExts(fi.Name(), sourceExts) {
            fmt.Println(fi.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
t.c
t.go
t.py
t1.go
t1.py
t2.go
```

---

For a special form of `strings.HasSuffix` start by copying the code from the [`strings` package](https://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go).

```
func HasSuffix(s, suffix string) bool {
    return len(s) >= len(suffix) && s[len(s)-len(suffix):] == suffix
}
```

Then modify it to suit your purpose. For example,

```
func hasSuffix(s, suffix string) bool {
    return len(s) >= len(suffix) &&
        strings.ToLower(s[len(s)-len(suffix):]) == strings.ToLower(suffix)
}
```